# Electron - sharing constants between main and renderer

Tags: electron

Is it possible to share constants between the main process and the renderer process in electron? I haven't been able to find an elegant solution.

I can share constants between renderer and preload. So far, it seems like exposing the constants through contextBridge is the only way.

Anyone have a cool way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean actual constants, like static strings or objects, then yes, it's possible. You can put these constants on a file (or files), and simply import them in both processes.

For ESM, [now supported since Electron 28](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/37535) (see [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/esm)), nothing special to do, just use `import`/`export`:

**constants.js**

```js
export const myFirstConst = "Hello";
export const mySecondConst = "World";
```

**Renderer & Main**

```js
import { myFirstConst, mySecondConst } from "./constants.js";
```

For CJS, you need to use CJS `exports` so it can be required on the main process. If your renderer uses a bundler, you need to make sure it supports CJS `exports` when using ES6 `import`. For [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) for example, [`sourceType`](https://babeljs.io/docs/options#sourcetype) has to be set to `"unambiguous"`.

**constants.js**

```js
const myFirstConst = "Hello";
const mySecondConst = "World";

module.exports = { myFirstConst, mySecondConst };
```

**Renderer**

```js
import { myFirstConst, mySecondConst } from "./constants";
```

**Main**

```js
const { myFirstConst, mySecondConst } = require("./constants.js");
```

If the constants depend on some renderer code, then you need to use the bridge.